# Multiple many to many relationships with the same two classes - Django

Tags: django, many-to-many, models

I have two classes that have two many to many relationships between them. Since the adjoining tables also have to have additional attributes, I explicitly defined them. But I'm getting an error that says I need to change the related names. Not sure where to do this. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Here's my models.py code:

```
class Client(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    objects = UserManager()

    def __repr__(self):
        return "<User object: {} {} {} {}>".format(self.first_name, 
self.last_name, self.email, self.password)

class Therapist(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    reviews = models.ManyToManyField(Client, through="Review")
    appts = models.ManyToManyField(Client, through="Appointment")
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    objects = UserManager()

    def __repr__(self):
        return "<Book object: {}>".format(self.title)



class Review(models.Model):
    reviewer = models.ForeignKey(Client, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    therapist_reviewed = models.ForeignKey(Therapist, 
on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    rating = models.IntegerField()
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    content = models.TextField()

    def __repr__(self):
        return "<Review object: {} {}>".format(self.book_reviewed, 
self.reviewer)

class Appointment(models.Model):
    booked_therapist = models.ForeignKey(Therapist, 
on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    booked_client = models.ForeignKey(Client, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    date = models.DateTimeField()
    massage = models.CharField(max_length=255)
```

Comment: share the traceback please

Comment: ERRORS:
application.Therapist.appts: (fields.E304) Reverse accessor for 'Therapist.appts' clashes with reverse accessor for 'Therapist.reviews'.
 HINT: Add or change a related_name argument to the definition for 'Therapist.appts' or 'Therapist.reviews'.
application.Therapist.reviews: (fields.E304) Reverse accessor for 'Therapist.reviews' clashes with reverse accessor for 'Therapist.appts'.
 HINT: Add or change a related_name argument to the definition for 'Therapist.reviews' or 'Therapist.appts'.

Answer (score 2):

```
class Therapist(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    reviews = models.ManyToManyField(Client, related_name='therapist_reviews', through="Review")
    appts = models.ManyToManyField(Client, related_name='therapist_appts', through="Appointment")
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    objects = UserManager()

    def __repr__(self):
        return "<Book object: {}>".format(self.title)
```

If you don't assign related_name for `many_to_many` field,the default related will set to model_lower_case_set,but when you has two `many_to_many` fields related to one same model,the default related_name for the two fileds is same as model_lower_case_set,this will cause conflict when use `related_name` to query queryset.

Comment: If you set foreign keys explicitly, why does it need a related name? And how would you use the foreign keys in tandem with the related name? Still a little foggy on this. Thank you.

Comment: [doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/db/examples/many_to_one/) explain this clear